# EXT Js: How to create a thread on load

Tags: javascript, multithreading, extjs

I wish to create a thread in EXT js which keep on makes a rest call after an interval of time untill Js is on browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```
setTimeout(function(){ <Make ajax call here> }, <interval in miliseconds>);
```

Did this solved your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not have the concepts of threads and parallel execution. However, it can fill the execution queue with a function to execute on a regular basis. The javascript function for this is

```
window.setInterval(fn, milliseconds);
```

If you really want to repeat the function runs forever, this is a good deal. While you could also stop execution using `window.clearInterval`, I would not do that if you are already using the ExtJS framework.

Because around these basic functions, ExtJS has created the `Task` object which you can start and stop at will. The ExtJS solution is more OOP style, which means cleaner code.

To see how to use it, the [official `Task` documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.util.TaskRunner.Task.html) ist your friend.